# TV Audio to Text for Android

Tags: android, audio, speech-to-text, digital

I know this sounds a bit strange, but I want to create an Android App (no Smart TV App) that "listens" to TV Audio and translates the (analog) Speech to Text.

Should I rather try to get the digital Audio on my phone via HDMI (is that even possible?) or rather use the Android Speech to Text API with the functionality to only listen to digital Audio instead of voice (different frequencies).

Comment: There's one application like this already.Can't freaking remember the name though :/.Sorry

Comment: At least it's somehow possible. I am running out of terms to describe it since I am neither an audio nor an android expert.

Comment: Shazam! This is the application I was using.Anyways, how it would go ,is like this: you will record a few seconds of a song ,than compare it (bit by bit I guess) with songs from a database.And that means you won't be needing only the TV, you ll be able to try it on any device that runs a song.Anyways,that's how you would wanna approach this thingy,but even if I would like to give you specific,I really don't know right now.I ll be back with details later, hopefully.

Comment: Yeah, it will be similar to Shazaam, but instead of recording just a couple of seconds I actually want to record a very long time (45 Minutes). I guess I need to split these recordings into 2-3 second recordings and then convert them to speech in parallel to the ongoing recording.

Comment: Oh wait, I went too far from your idea.Practically,you want to "translate" from audio to text,that different than Shazam I guess.You should look at how Google's Voice recognition works I guess?

Comment: http://chrome.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/hello-browser.html

Comment: Yes, I hope it works with regular audio as well, not only with voice.